# Lifecycle methods gets called Twice at initial render and at re-render phase

Tags: reactjs

- When I console.log() in every life cycle methods, in Chrome console, I see every method had been called twice.
- So, I created a new React app. And did console.log() in render. It still gets called twice at initial render.
- I tried finding the answer on stackoverflow, but they have solved this problem with neglecting by writing the script, which is not a solution. Because, even they can show the render gets called once, it's actually getting called Twice in the background.

-- I uninstalled node, visual studio. Removed any residue. And installed again.  Still I haven't been able to solve this problem.

- I will most thankful. Thanks in advance.

```
class Person extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("[Person.js] constructor1");
    console.log("[Person.js] constructor2");
  }
  render() {
    console.log("[Person.js] render1");
    console.log("[Person.js] render2");
    return <h1>Person Component</h1>;
  }
}
```

Concole outputs:

```
Person.js:6 [Person.js] constructor1
Person.js:7 [Person.js] constructor2
Person.js:6 [Person.js] constructor1
Person.js:7 [Person.js] constructor2
Person.js:10 [Person.js] render1
Person.js:11 [Person.js] render2
Person.js:10 [Person.js] render1
Person.js:11 [Person.js] render2
```

Comment: Since you don't do any asynchronous action on component mount and also there is no props passed here, I suspect the parent component might be the cause. Try to check if the parent is rerendering too.

Answer (score 3):

Please check your index.js, if your App.js is wrapped in `<React.StrictMode>` then it will call life cycle hooks twice.

To resolve your issue you just need to unwrap your App.js from `<React.StrictMode>`.

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Please follow the link to get a detailed idea about [React.StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) and also
[Detecting unexpected side effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

Answer (score -1):

to remove unnecessary render in react you can use `PureComponent` for class Component and `React.memo()` for functional Component .

this will check for props change and re-render the component if only it's props change. this is useful when the `parent` frequently trigger a state change that doesn't affect the child.